# Empty and broken pdf file downloaded from UI using spring mvc and apache pdf box

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, pdfbox

The following code works fine with no error I am able to download file with the name as specified in code but the issue is there is no content printed to it and when I open the file I get error saying file is damaged. While I just save the file somewhere I get proper file with contents.

**From UI:**

```
var jsonStrToSend = JSON.stringify( jsonObjToSend );
jsonStrToSend = jsonStrToSend.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
var url = '/'+appPath+'/reportgeneration' ;
var $form = $('<form enctype=\'application/json\' action="' + url + '" method="post">').append($('<input type="hidden" name="data" id="data" value="' + jsonStrToSend + '" />'));
$form.appendTo("body").submit();
```

**In Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reportgeneration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
           public @ResponseBody void reportgeneration(HttpServletRequest request,
                 HttpServletResponse response){ 
           Map returnMapMessage = new HashMap();
           int resultData =0;
           HttpSession httpsessionObj = request.getSession(false);
           try{
               PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
               PDPage intro_page = new PDPage();

               doc.addPage( intro_page );

               PDPageContentStream contentStream_itro =
                        new PDPageContentStream(doc, intro_page);

               //Some stuff.......

               String fileName = reportName+"_"+tempDate.getDate()+"-"+tempDate.getMonth()+"-"+tempDate.getYear()+" "+tempDate.getHours()+tempDate.getMinutes()+".pdf";
               //doc.save("/test/webapp/reports/"+fileName);
               response.setContentType("application/pdf");
               PDStream ps=new PDStream(doc);
               InputStream is=ps.createInputStream();
               String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
               String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
               response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching
               response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
               org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
               response.flushBuffer();
               is.close();
               doc.close();
```

Comment: You don't send the generated pdf but merely the contents of a newly generated, empty pdf stream object.

Comment: I did not understand you properly. are you taking about pdstream object as that have the data in it but where am i doing it all wrong. What I think is I am sending the stream object and the file header which should give me the file in ui but something that I am doing wrong

Comment: *"pdstream object as that have the data"* - I'm talking about the `PDStream` object but it does not have any data. You merely created it as an empty steam and added no content. Thus, when you retrieve an `InputStream` from it, that stream is nearly empty. In particular it contains no part of the pdf you want to send.

Comment: my assumption is that PDStream ps=new PDStream(doc); will lead to copy contents in doc to ps object correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @mkl  I just realise inputstream is empty but how to achieve this in apache pdfbox i mean to get the contents

Comment: So much weird stuff there. `PDStream ps=new PDStream(doc);` won't help with anything. To save a doc, use doc.save(). Also don't forget to close contentStream_itro.

Comment: Please  have a look at the many examples in the source code download, e.g. HelloWorldTTF.java.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks got it saved the doc to the ByteArrayOutputStream which it sent it back as response converting it to byteArray and now its working just fine.

Comment: @SiddP great to hear that... please delete the question or answer it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing out doc.save() as I felt it not necessary as I was not storing file anywhere in the drive. But below code just works fine.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.save(output);
doc.close();
response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+fileName+"\"");
response.getOutputStream().write(output.toByteArray());
```